# How to call specific function in PowerShell script form Command Line?

Tags: powershell, command-line, ini

I want to call the specific function in my powershell script from command line. But It return me error like this :
Key cannot be null.

```
Parameter name: key
$Get = $ini_file.($a_section).($b_node)

Key cannot be null.
Parameter name: key
$Output = $ini_file.($a_section).($b_node) | Out-File $Store\Val ...
```

Here is my code:

```
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$FilePath,
    $ini, $a_section, $b_node, $c_store,
    $a, $b, $c
)

function Get-File {
    $input_file = $FilePath
    $ini_file = @{}

    Get-Content $input_file | ForEach-Object {
        $_.Trim()
    } | Where-Object {
        $_ -notmatch '^(;|$)'
    } | ForEach-Object {
        if ($_ -match '^\[.*\]$') {
            $section = $_ -replace '\[|\]'
            $ini_file[$section] = @{}
        } else {
            $key, $value = $_ -split '\s*=\s*', 2
            $ini_file[$section][$key] = $value
        }
    }

    $Get = $ini_file.($a_section).($b_node)
    $Store = $c_store
    $Output = $ini_file.($a_section).($b_node) | Out-File $Store\Value.cmd
}

function Write-File {
    Import-Module PsIni
    $ff = Get-IniContent $FilePath
    $ff["$a"]["$b"] = "$c"  
    $ff | Out-IniFile -FilePath $FilePath -Force
}

# Calling the function with the global parameter $FilePath
Write-File $FilePath $a $b $c 
Get-File $FilePath $ini $a_section $b_node $c_store
```

The way I call each function from command line is:

Call function `Get-File`:

```
powershell.ps1 Get-File -FilePath C:\User\file.ini -a_section Information -b_node Name -c_store C:\User\
```

If I run that command, I still can get the `value` of INI file, but it returns the above error. If I REMOVE this part `Write-File $FilePath $a $b $c` It will not return any error.

It looks like I can't use "calling the function" at the same time. But I am not sure about it.

My INI file

```
    [Information]
    Name=Joyce
    Age=12
```

## UPDATED CODE:

```
Function Read-File
{
    Param(
    [parameter(mandatory=$true)]$FilePath,
    [parameter(mandatory=$true)] $ini,
    [parameter(mandatory=$true)] $a_section,
    [parameter(mandatory=$true)] $b_node,
    [parameter(mandatory=$true)] $c_store
    )
    $input_file = $FilePath
    $ini_file = @{}

    Get-Content $input_file | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Trim()
    } | Where-Object {
    $_ -notmatch '^(;|$)'
    } | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_ -match '^\[.*\]$') {
        $section = $_ -replace '\[|\]'
        $ini_file[$section] = @{}
    } else {
        $key, $value = $_ -split '\s*=\s*', 2
        $ini_file[$section][$key] = $value
    }
    }

     $Get = $ini_file.($a_section).($b_node)
     $Store = $c_store
     $Output = $ini_file.($a_section).($b_node) | Out-File $Store\Value.cmd
}

#---------------------------------------------------------------#
Function Write-File
{
    Param(
    [parameter(mandatory=$true)]$FilePath,
    [parameter(mandatory=$true)] $a,
    [parameter(mandatory=$true)] $b,
    [parameter(mandatory=$true)] $c
    )
    Import-Module PsIni
    $ff = Get-IniContent $FilePath
    $ff["$a"]["$b"] = "$c"  
    $ff | Out-IniFile -FilePath $FilePath -Force

}

$cmd, $params = $args
& $cmd @params
```

Comment: This code is working

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The way you're trying to invoke the function does not work, because you're passing arguments to the script, but never do anything with them. If you want the function to be invoked automatically when the script is run invoke the function from within the script.

```
function Write-IniFile {
    Param(
        ...
    )
    ...
}
Write-IniFile -FilePath C:\Users\file.ini -a Name -b Joyce -c 1309
```

and run the script like this:

```
PS.ps1
```

Otherwise dot-source the script before invoking the function:

```
. PS.ps1
Write-IniFile -FilePath C:\Users\file.ini -a Name -b Joyce -c 1309
```

If you want to be able to run the script with parameters and have those passed to the function use the first approach, but splat `$args` on the function:

```
function Write-IniFile {
    Param(
        ...
    )
    ...
}
Write-IniFile @args
```

and invoke the script like this:

```
PS.ps1 -FilePath C:\Users\file.ini -a Name -b Joyce -c 1309
```

---

**Edit:**

If you have a script with multiple functions and want to be able to invoke any of them by running the script you could *split'n'splat* the script parameters:

`PS.ps1`:

```
function Foo {
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        $x
    )
    ...
}

function Bar {
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        $y,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        $z
    )
    ...
}

$cmd, $params = $args
& $cmd @params
```

Invocation:

```
PS.ps1 Foo -x 'some'          # invoke Foo() with the given arguments
PS.ps1 Bar -y 'or' -z 'other' # invoke Bar() with the given arguments
```

The statement

```
$cmd, $params = $args
```

assigns the first argument to the variable `$cmd` and the rest of the arguments to the variable `$params`. The next statement

```
& $cmd @params
```

invokes `$cmd` via the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-3.0) (`&`) and [splats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-3.0) the parameters in `$params`.

Comment: But my expectation, when I have 2 or 3 function, I can use this command 
`PS.ps1 function1 FilePath -a Name -b Joyce -c 1309` if Ijust want to execute function1.
`PS.ps1 function2......`    If I just wwan to execute function2

Comment: @Job You should have explained that in your question. See updated answer.

Comment: It still not solve my problem. I updated the question.

Comment: @Job Because you removed the parameter definitions from your functions and put a global parameter definition in your script. Where did my answer suggest to do that? Anyway, updated for clarity.

Comment: I create new updated code. Is that what u mean? @Ansgar Wiechers?

Comment: Updated code is working. Thanks a lot @Ansgar Wiechers